# Zend Framework 2 match any route starting with given segment

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

In my Zend Framework 2 application I need to build a route matching anything starting with a given segment.

To be clear, consider I want to match anything starting with `/foo`, so `/foo`, `/foo/bar`, `/foo/baz`, `/foo/bar/baz`, ...

I could do it using a `Wildcard` router

```
'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
'options' => [
    'route'    => '/foo',
    'defaults' => [
        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ],
],
'may_terminate' => true,
'child_routes' => [
    'anything' => [
        'type' => 'Wildcard'
    ]
]
```

But the `Wildcard` is deprecated, so I'd like to avoid using it. Is there a way to obtain what I'm looking for in another way?

Comment: Hi, Which it is the maximum amount of allowed parameters for your url route?

Comment: @JorelC in theory, I don't want to have a maximum amount of allowed parameters

Comment: What exactly makes your think the `Wilcard` router is deprecated? As far is I know and can see it isn't. Edit: I see, the documentation states it's deprecated, but nothing in the code itself points to it (weird!). Anyway, you could look into using the Regex router.

Comment: @netiul Yes, I guess I could use the Regex router, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way, also because in the documentation, where they say that Wildcard is deprecated, they suggest to use Segment instead

Comment: I understand, but unfortunately Segment can't do that kind of wildcarding. It matches parts seperated by slashes for as many as you define them: /foo[/:a1[/:a2[/:a3[/:a4[/:a5[/:a6]]]]]]. You could write your own adapted Segment router of course..

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to match any route and the ones you gave are just examples or do want to match multiple prefixes at once? Anyway, you can always implement your own route.

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim The ones that I gave are just examples. I want to match all the routes starting with a given prefix

Comment: Then I would go with a regex or custom route.

Answer (score 0):

```
'foo' => [
  'type' => 'Regex',
  'options' => [
        'regex' => '/foo(/(?<action>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?',
        'defaults' => [
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
            'module' => 'Application',
            'controller' => 'Foo',
            'action' => 'index',
        ],
        'spec' => '/foo/%action%',
    ],
],
```